# How to find the exact or approximate value of an absolutely convergent inifinite series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

When I was fiddling around with the Riemann Zeta function I found this infinite series as a result of plugging in $\frac{1}{2}$+*i* as z. (*i* is removed from the series below because the calculator I was using, Symbolab, doesn't know what *i* means.)

$\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty$ $\frac{1}{\sqrt n(\cos(\ln(n)) + \sin(\ln(n)))}$

Inputting this expression into Symbolab to see if it was convergent or not, Symbolab says that it was absolutely convergent (the form $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty$ |*f(x)*| is convergent, but not $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty$ *f(x)*), but it didn't tell me what it absolutely converges *to*.

So, my question is, what is the value that $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty$ $\frac{1}{\sqrt n(\cos(\ln(n)) + \sin(\ln(n)))}$ converges to? And, if you could, I would also like to know *how* to find the value the previously mentioned infinite series converges to. (Also, approximate value is okay, but if there exists an exact value I would also like to know that too. Thank you!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolute convergence implies convergence so Symbolab may have made a mistake.

I don't think this series converges. To see this, you may apply the $n$th term test for divergence (sometimes called the vanishing criterion) which says that given a series $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty a_n$, if $a_n \not\to 0$, then $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty a_n$ diverges. It may be easier to write $\sqrt{n}(\cos(\ln(n)) + \sin(\ln(n))) = \sqrt{2n}\sin(\ln(n) + \frac{\pi}{4})$. Also note that $a_n \to 0$ if and only if $|a_n| \to 0$.

**Edit:**
I realised that the argument is a little complicated so here are the details. (If someone has a simpler argument, I'd love to see it.)

Let $a_n = \sqrt{2n}\sin(\ln(n) + \frac{\pi}{4})$. We will show that $\frac{1}{a_n}$ diverges. We will do this by finding a subsequence $a_{n_k}$ that converges to zero causing $\frac{1}{a_{n_k}}$ to diverge. (If a subsequence diverges, so does the sequence itself.)

First note that $\sin x = 0$ if and only if $x = k\pi$ for some $k \in \mathbb Z$. So, $\sin(\ln(n) + \frac{\pi}{4}) = 0$ if and only if $\ln x = (k - \frac{1}{4})\pi$ for some $k \in \mathbb Z$.

Now, for every $k \in \mathbb N$, there exists $x_{k} \in \mathbb R$ such that $\ln x_{k} = (k - \frac{1}{4})\pi$ by surjectivity of $\ln$. Let $n_{k} = \lfloor x_{k} \rceil$ and $r_{k} = x_{k} - n_{k}$ where $\lfloor \cdot \rceil$ denotes rounding and $\ln x_{k} = (k - \frac{1}{4})\pi$. So, $\ln x_{k} = \ln(n_{k} + r_{k})$ and $r_{k} < 1$.

Now, note that $\frac{d}{dx} \ln x = \frac{1}{x}$ which is a strictly decreasing function on $\mathbb R^{\geq0}$. So, a small perturbation by $r_{k} < 1$ in the argument becomes less significant as the argument increases. Also note that as $k$ increases, $x_k$ increases and so does $\ln x_k$ because $\ln$ is an increasing function.  Thus, $|\ln(x_{k} - r_{k}) - \ln x_{k}| = |\ln n_{k} - (k - \frac{1}{4})\pi| \to 0$ as $k \to \infty$. Hence, $a_{n_{k}} \to 0$ and therefore, $\frac{1}{a_{n_{k}}}$ diverges.

Comment: Ahh, okay thank you! I didn't think Symbolab made a mistake because I use it so often and it's always correct, that's nice to know that it isn't always correct for things like this. I've also just learned about this test! Very new to infinite series.

Comment: How is the vanishing criterion relevant here? $\frac{1}{\sqrt n(\cos(\ln(n)) + \sin(\ln(n)))}$ vanishes for $n\rightarrow 0$

Comment: @user619894 You need to take the limit as $n \to \infty$ for the vanishing criterion and this limit does not exist for the sequence in question.

Comment: @TheSurgeonofDeath sorry, that was a typo, I meant $n \rightarrow \infty$

Comment: @user619894 Why do you think that $\frac{1}{\sqrt n(\cos(\ln(n)) + \sin(\ln(n)))} \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$?

Comment: Actually, I believe it is true that it doesn't converge, since the $\sin$ can approach $0$ infinitely close, but that needs to be shown, or at least give an argument. Your answer didn't explain it.

Comment: @user619894 That is fair criticism. I have provided the details now. I refrained from doing so earlier because I wanted to leave something for the reader to do. Initially, I came up with a simple argument in my head utilising the hints I had given. However, I found a flaw when I wrote down the details. The next argument I found was slightly complicated so I chose to provide the details in the answer. I hope this is satisfactory.

Comment: Upvoted, but I think this is overkill since $\sum {1\over \sqrt n }$ diverges